# Rewrite requests for non-existing images to Resizing controller

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, codeigniter-3

I have my images in /CIAppScaffolding/public/upload/ and wish to resize them to some fixed sizes on the fly.

For this, I made a controller `Resize` with method `index` which does the resizing.

```
public function index($location = '', $size = '', $image = '') {
    //Resizing code here
}
```

Now, to rewrite only requests for images which don't exist, I wrote following rewrite rules, which seem to be taking out `CIAppScaffolding` from `PATH_TRANSLATED`, and I get a 404 (by Codeigniter).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /CIAppScaffolding/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^public/upload/([a-z]+)/(large|catalog|thumb)/([^/]+\.(?:jpg|png|jpeg))$ index.php/resize/index/$1/$2/$3 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Edit:
For now, I've resorted to the following, which works, but this should also be possible with just .htaccess rewrite rules.

```
$route['^public/upload/([a-z]+)/(large|catalog|thumb|banner)/([^/]+\.(?:jpg|png|jpeg))$'] = 'resize/index/$1/$2/$3';
```

Answer (score 0):

**I tried with Codeigniter 3 with following code writen in htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /ci-admin/

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/ci-admin/assets/uploads/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^assets/uploads/(large|catalog|AdminUser)/([^/]+\.jpg|\.png|\.jpeg)$ index.php/resize/index/$1/$2 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

What I found after printing Server variables:

```
[REQUEST_URI] => /ci-admin/assets/uploads/AdminUser/IMG_20140623_2047229.jpg
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /ci-admin/index.php
[PATH_INFO] => /resize/index/AdminUser/IMG_20140623_2047229.jpg
[PATH_TRANSLATED] => D:\wamp\www\resize\index\AdminUser\IMG_20140623_2047229.jpg
[PHP_SELF] => /ci-admin/index.php/resize/index/AdminUser/IMG_20140623_2047229.jpg
```

All rules are working fine except CodeIgniter itself interprets "[PATH_TRANSLATED]" in different way or overwriting our htaccess rule, so it throws 404 error.

We need to find out how CI have been handling these kind of requests. Still debugging where we are lacking.

Let me know if you find any success.